connect Android Phone to Ubuntu
I'm coming from an iPhone and iMac where the connection between the phone and the computer is seamless. Is there any way I can connect an Android phone to 24.04 primarily so I can send text messages from the desktop the way Messages works on macOS?

Yes. Install KDE Connect in Kubuntu, or GSConnect if you are using regular ubuntu

What research have you done? What have you tried?

This question is similar to: Are there any applications to manage SMS messaging on an Android from Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
